# updating object with Object.assign not production desire result

Tags: javascript, object

I need to update existing object data

```
oldData = {
  "fnol": {
    "operationStatus": {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "statusMessage": "Operation was successful."
    },
    "data": {
      "policies": [
        {
          "formattedPolicyNumber": "abc8",
          "producerCode": "TP109"
        },
        {
          "formattedPolicyNumber": "abc8",
          "producerCode": "TP110"
        }
      ],
      "user": {
        "login": "URGENTNOTICES@test.COM",
        "firstName": "firsname",
        "lastName": "lastname",
        "dateOfBirth": "1960-01-01",
        "phone": {
          "number": "3242342342",
          "extension": "5454"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

need to update

```
let editedData = {
    "fnol":{
    "data":{
        "user":{
                "phone":{"number":"","extension":""}
            }   
        }
    }
}

editedData = editedData.fnol.data.user.phone.number = '0000000000';
```

So I am trying to update user phone number using

```
newData = new Object.assign({}, oldData, editedData);
```

But still I am getting oldData object with out updated number ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: drop the `new` keyword: `newData =  Object.assign({}, oldData, editedData);`

Comment: @DacreDenny dropping "new" didn't worked

Comment: oldData.fnol.data.user.phone.number = '0000000000';

var newData = Object.assign({}, oldData);

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel if its workes only on top levels than how i should achieve my objective ? like update exiting object with out spoiling original copy

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oJNpOQ  ,  you can directly assign oldData instead of assigning to variable and updating newData object

Comment: @NagaSaiA I need to get a new copy of old object with updated values with out destroying original data object  .

Comment: editedData = oldData.fnol.data.user.phone.number = '0000000000';  this line already changes original data object

Comment: @NagaSaiA typo error its edited.fnol.data.phone.number = ''000000000'. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use below option

1. First assign oldData to editedData
2. Change phone number of editedData
3. Assign to newData

```js
var oldData = {
  "fnol": {
    "operationStatus": {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "statusMessage": "Operation was successful."
    },
    "data": {
      "policies": [
        {
          "formattedPolicyNumber": "abc8",
          "producerCode": "TP109"
        },
        {
          "formattedPolicyNumber": "abc8",
          "producerCode": "TP110"
        }
      ],
      "user": {
        "login": "URGENTNOTICES@test.COM",
        "firstName": "firsname",
        "lastName": "lastname",
        "dateOfBirth": "1960-01-01",
        "phone": {
          "number": "3242342342",
          "extension": "5454"
        }
      }
    }
  }
} 

let editedData = Object.assign({}, oldData)


eeditedData = editedData.fnol.data.user.phone.number = '0000000000';

var newData = Object.assign({}, oldData, editedData);

console.log(newData);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QzWaXG?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You might use a function like this to make changes to (or add) the value along a path:

```js
const oldData = {"fnol": {"data": {"policies": [{"formattedPolicyNumber": "abc8", "producerCode": "TP109"}, {"formattedPolicyNumber": "abc8", "producerCode": "TP110"}], "user": {"dateOfBirth": "1960-01-01", "firstName": "firsname", "lastName": "lastname", "login": "URGENTNOTICES@test.COM", "phone": {"extension": "5454", "number": "3242342342"}}}, "operationStatus": {"statusCode": "200", "statusMessage": "Operation was successful."}}}

const None = Symbol()

const setPath = ([ p = None, ...ps ]) => (val) => obj => 
  p === None
    ? { ...obj }
    : ps.length == 0
      ? { ...obj, [p]: val }
      : { ...obj, [p]: setPath (ps) (val) (obj[p]) }

const newData = setPath 
  (['fnol', 'data', 'user', 'phone', 'number']) 
  ('0000000000')
  (oldData)

console.log(newData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {height: 100vh !important}
```

This does not modify your original data.  It only handles objects, not arrays.  Adding those would not be difficult.

If you wanted to use a `.`-separated string rather than an array, you could add a gloss to that version like this:

```
const setPathStr = (str) => setPath(str.split('.'))

const newData = setPathStr
  ('fnol.data.user.phone.number')
  ('0000000000')
  (oldData)
```

But note the reduced flexibility in this.  The nodes in the path can no longer include the `.` character.  This may or may not be an issue for you, but for a general utility function, it's a real concern.

This function takes inspiration from Ramda's [`assocPath`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath) function. (I'm a Ramda author.)

Comment: This is way overkill.

Comment: @fuzz: Well, sure if this is a one-off.  But a function like this will let you set any path on any object in a non-destructive manner, and add that path if one of the intermediate nodes happens not to exist.  Since the objective as stated is so trivial (see the answer from Naga Sai A), I was assuming that the problem is more general.  If not, well, hey, I had fun creating a cleaner version of `setPath`/`setPathStr`.  :-)

Comment: Agreed, great resource for the future!